# Regex to capture nested functions in a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture all the function names present in an expresison, for example:

> **DECODE**(TRUE, NOT **ISNULL**(parameter1),VARIABLE1, **ISNULL**(Parameter2) AND NOT **ISNULL**(parameter1),Variable3, **ISNULL**(parameter) AND **ISNULL**(parameter) AND NOT **ISNULL**(parameter),VARIABLE2)

I had tried

```regex
([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*\(([\w\s\,]+)?\)\s*)+
```

The regex is capturing all the function names except **DECODE**.
Could anyone tell what mistake I'm doing?

Comment: Will you ever have string literals like `"foo(123)"` in your expressoins? That should throw things off.

Comment: I also updated my answer after your edit

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*)(\(.+?\))
```

Basically, it capture 2 groups: before the `(` and inside `(*)`. You can choose which group to extract later.
You can watch the demo in here: https://regex101.com/r/9ILSYn/1

Or you can just put in the `?:` in the later group to mark it as a non-capturing group

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*)(?:\(.+?\))
```

In your before-edit regex, you didn't split the capturing groups so it mixed the first function with the parameters.

In your updated regex, you are capturing the groups with word and white space inside the `(*)`, which is not including some character like `(`, so it didn't capture the `DECODE`

Comment: That wouldn't capture the m and n of this string: `abc(def(ghi(jkl)m)n)`